# SharePoint Rest api to get a single user profile property

Tags: 2013, rest, user-profile-property

I'm trying to retrieve a single user property from a jsom script.

The property is a custom one, not in the default schema.

When I retrieve

```
http://server/sites/coll/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/GetMyProperties/
UserProfileProperties
```

I get all properties.

When I retrieve

```
http://server/sites/coll/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/GetMyProperties/
UserProfileProperties/MySingleProperty
```

an error is thrown.

I also tried:

```
http://server/sites/coll/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/GetMyProperties/
UserProfileProperties/?select=MySingleProperty
```

It does not fail, but all properties are still returned.

What is the correct syntax to retrieve my property?

**[Edit]** Don't know if it matters, but my property has an hyphen in its name: `My-Single-Property`. I tried to escape using unicode like this: `My%u002dSingle%002dProperty`, but without success.

You can repro using an OOB field:

> _api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/GetMyProperties/?$select=SPS-JobTitle
>   _api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/GetMyProperties/?$select=SPS%2dJobTitle
>   _api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/GetMyProperties/?$select=SPS%u002dJobTitle

Comment: Can you specify is there any specific property you are looking for, or you want all properties for a specified user?

Comment: @Gaurravs: not sure to understand. I want to retrieve a single property for the current logged in user

Answer (score 1):

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/
GetMyProperties?$select=**YourPropertNameHere**
```

This should give a specific single property

I hope this is what you are searching for.

Comment: This does not works for custom properties.

Comment: Any option to make it work for custom property?

Answer (score 0):

You can use of `$filter` in REST API.

E.g

```
http://server/sites/coll/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/GetMyProperties/
UserProfileProperties/?$select=MySingleProperty&$filter=COLUMN1 eq 'VALUE11'
```

Reference :

http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html

Comment: This does not works. All properties are still retrieved

Comment: Let me do some search , i'll be back to you.

Comment: Are you getting your custom property in all properties?

Comment: Yes. I can see my custom property